# html5 how to create effect like templatemonster?

Tags: html

I have no knowledge of html5, and I need to make a site with effect of http://www.templatemonster.com/flash-templates/32799.html in HTML(no flash at all).

Anyone knows if there's a available html5 source that can share.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: tbh, you have to be really good with html5 / canvas / js to achieve something like this...

Comment: It seems to be Flash. Anyway.. you have to get familiar with canvas drawing in HTML5 if you don't want to use Flash. Maybe that is a starting point. Search SO for 'HTML5 3d canvas' and you might find what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable with CSS 3D transforms and CSS transitions and a bit of JavaScript. Of course browser support may be limited.

Here's an example done in 10 minutes (Webkit only!) http://jsfiddle.net/bZdTE/

The interesting bits are:

**transform: perspective**.

```
#box {
    // perspective() changes the "depth"; 
    // rotateY() - rotation; 
    // and translateZ() makes the whole area react to mouse pointer; 
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY( 45deg ) translateZ(100px);
}
```

learn more: http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html

**transitions** make the red squares appear/disappear with animation.

```
.grid .row > div span { 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:20px; 
    height:0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    // define which properties should animate (height: and bottom: ) 
    // and how fast the animation should be (200ms);
    -webkit-transition: height 200ms ease-in, bottom 200ms; 
}

.grid .row > div:hover span {
    height:100%;  
    bottom:0;
}
```

learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

**JavaScript** to change the perspective when cursor moves left/right

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var move = function(e){
    var s = "perspective( 500px ) rotateY( deg ) translateZ(100px)";
     // this calculation is a random guess, just to make it work. should be something more carefully crafted;
    s = s.replace( 'deg', ((e.clientX-200) / 400) * 45 + 'deg' );
    box.style.webkitTransform = s;
}

document.body.addEventListener( 'mousemove', move, true );
```

To make it work in Firefox and modern IE one should add [vendor prefixes](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/) to CSS and JavaScript code.